# The proof of the multivariable chain rule (Vector form)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Let $f$ be a function defined on an open set $U$, and let $X(t)$ be a curve such that $X(t)$ is contained in $U$ for all $t$.

We define the function $g(t)=f(X(t))$, I want to know what is $dg/dt$, this is my attempt :
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(X(t+h))-f(X(t))}{h}$$
Now let $k=X(t+h)-X(t)\iff X(t+h)=k+X(t)$,
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(X(t)+k)-f(X(t))}{h}$$
I'm gonna use a trick now :
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(X(t)+k)-f(X(t))}{h}\frac{k}{k}=
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(X(t)+k)-f(X(t))}{k}\frac{k}{h}$$
remmember that as $h\to 0$, $k\to 0$, so we get
$$\frac{dg}{dt}=f'(X(t))\cdot X'(t)$$
but this is result is completely false because $X'(t)$ is a curve and $f'(X(t))$ is a function, so multiplying both we get a curve, but $dg/dt$ is a function.

please help me find the mistake.

Comment: $f'(X(t))$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix, $X'(t)$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector, so their product yields a number as expected.

Comment: but what is $f'(X(t))$ exactly, I mean it is the derivative of what? @peek-a-boo

Comment: It's the derivative of $f$ evaluated at the point $X(t)$.

Comment: You write $\frac{k}{k}$. However, division for vectors is not well defined. So the line where you say: "I'm gonna use a trick" does not make any mathematical sense.

Comment: I've multiplied the numerator and the denominator by $k$. $k/k$ is just a shorthand @Yadeses

Comment: Assuming $f$ real, where is $U$? $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ @zkutch

Comment: Could you please extend the time of your question a little, as I saw it only yesterday. Of course, I cannot guarantee anything, but if I had at least another day, I would have thought about it a little.

Comment: how can I do that? is that even possible? @zkutch

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. May be it can be asked or find in some help of this site.

Comment: I will rebound the problem later after the bounty expires @zkutch

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find it.

Comment: I hope I made it in time and you don't have to reopen the question. Write if/when you'll need to reveal any place in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think one can proceed via generalized [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). Indeed, suppose $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable. Then $f$ admits a taylor series expanded about the point $X(t)$ to arrive at:
\begin{equation}
f(X(t+h))=f(X(t))+{(X(t+h)-X(t))}^T\cdot Df(X(t))+R(X(t))),
\end{equation}
where $R(X(t))$ is the remainder term. Plugging in the appropriate expression into the definition of the derivative, we find that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dg}{dt}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(X(t+h))-f(X(t))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{{(X(t+h)-X(t))}^T\cdot Df(X(t))+R(X(t))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{{(X(t+h)-X(t))}^T}{h}\cdot Df(X(t))+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{R(X(t))}{h}\\
&=X'(t)^T\cdot Df(X(t)),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where it's not hard to see that the remainder term vanishes in the limit and one arrives at the desired expression.

Answer (score 0):

Let me base answer on Vladimir A. Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, Springer, 2016, page 441, Differentiation of a Composition of Mappings (Chain Rule).

Assuming we have curve $X\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$, for $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with given in OP properties i.e. exists derivative of composition $g=f \circ X$ for point $y=X(t)$, then it will be calculate by formula

$$g'(t)=(f \circ X)'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
 \partial_1 f(y) & \partial_2 f(y) & \cdots & \partial_n f(y)
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
 \partial_1 X^1(t) \\
 \partial_1 X^2(t) \\
 \cdots \\
\partial_1 X^n(t) 
\end{bmatrix} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\partial_i f(y) \cdot \partial_1 X^i(t)$$